# Redundant duplicates obviated by general references

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, exact-duplicates, specific-question

The question, [What's a word for “to eliminate the need for”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100537/whats-a-word-for-to-eliminate-the-need-for), has been voted as a duplicate of [Is there a word that means “make someone (or something) redundant”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52112/is-there-a-word-that-means-make-someone-or-something-redundant) which is itself closed as a general reference question. IMO, one or both of these questions needs reopening. I think that the questions are not *exact* duplicates in as much as one talks about the redundancy of the *need for something* while the other simply talks about the redundancy *of something*; a sufficiently distinct nuance.

In any case, we do entertain single word questions on this site and therefore the Dec '11 question ought to be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ouch—that really shouldn't have happened. I didn't notice the original question was closed, so that one is reopened now.

As for whether or not they're duplicates or not—while they're not literally duplicates, I believe they are sufficiently the same question, which is why I voted to close it. I don't feel that strongly about it, so if the community wants to reopen it, that's fine by me.

Comment: I kinda thought this would happen! I also had no strong feelings about Robert Cartaino's original closure, but it doesn't seem right to leave the first one closed and the second one open. I certainly don't think OP's "distinction" justifies calling them different questions that should both be kept open.

Comment: This is clearly the responsibility of the Department of Redundancy Department.